# angularjs java and velocity app

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs, velocity

I'm simply just trying to create an angularjs app inside my current java/velocity webapp that I have running locally. I am coming across issues where I am getting: **Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module...** Now by simply googling this issue it tells me to import angular-route.js, which I already am, but still seem to be getting this error.

Here is what is currently in the head.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Here is the html/vm file where I define the html for my app. (this is located inside the body of the page)

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="AvengersCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="search.$" />
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="actor in avengers.cast | filter:search">
                <td>{{actor.name}}</td>
                <td>{{actor.character}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript I have loading in my main.js

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
    myApp.factory('Avengers', function() {
        var Avengers = {};
        Avengers.cast = [{
            name: "Robert Downey Jr.",
            character: "Tony Stark / Iron Man"
        }, {
            name: "Chris Evans",
            character: "Steve Rogers / Captain America"
        }, {
            name: "Mark Buffalo",
            character: "Bruce Banner / The Hulk"
        }];
        return Avengers;
    })

    function AvengersCtrl($scope, Avengers) {
        $scope.avengers = Avengers;
    }
```

For the life of me I cant quite figure out why I continue to get that error. Curious to know if this is an issue with my current java app build and how angular might have issues running in that environment? but I really have no idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're getting the Uncaught error because of the search.$ in your input ng-model. If not, try to create an plnkr so we can help you out, if it's still necessary offcourse...

Answer (score 0):

The issue maybe in the way you labeled your controller. I'd give this syntax a try.

```
    myApp.controller("AvengersCtrl", function($scope, Avengers) {
    $scope.avengers = Avengers;
    }
```